# transfer file and form data in post request using RestTemplate between two applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have set up two application that is

1. Document server (8000)
2. App server (4000)

both are working fine individually (tested using Postman ).

a problem occurs when I am receiving a file and form data from UI / Postman to App server and transferring to Document and form data using Rest templet to the Document Server.
at same time App server is giving me an below error.

```
15:33:56.360 [http-nio-4206-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for "http://localhost:8000/docserver/api/webservicegetway/savefile"
15:33:56.428 [http-nio-4206-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
15:33:56.909 [http-nio-4206-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for "http://localhost:8000/docserver/api/webservicegetway/savefile" resulted in 406 (null); invoking error handler
15:33:56.916 [http-nio-4206-exec-10] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/appserver] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 406 null] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 406 null
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:766)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:724)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:600)
at com.org.appserver.main.services.DocServerService.transferFileToDocServer(DocServerService.java:101)
```

and getting following an issue at doc server

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
```

My RestWebservice code is below one:-

App Server:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadTest", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
private WebserviceResultSet fileUpload_Test( @RequestParam( "file" ) MultipartFile file,@RequestParam( "filename" ) String filesource,@RequestParam( "filepassword" ) String filepassword, Model p_model ) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    WebserviceResultSet result=new WebserviceResultSet();  
    if ( file.isEmpty() ) {
        result.addErrormessage("Empty or Corrupted file upload");
        return result;
    }

            byte[] l_bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path l_path = Paths.get("C:\\Eclipse_workspace\\"+ file.getOriginalFilename() );
            Path p=Files.write( l_path, l_bytes );



            DocServerService docServerService=new DocServerService();
            docServerService.transferFileToDocServer(file, filesource, filepassword);



    return result;

}
```

Doc Server:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "savefile", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
private WebserviceResultSet saveFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile p_file,
        @RequestParam("filename") String filename,
        @RequestParam("filepassword") String filepassword, Model p_model,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    WebserviceResultSet savefile = new WebserviceResultSet();

    String applicationctxpath = request.getRealPath(request.getContextPath());

    String directoryName = applicationctxpath + File.separator +ROOT_PATH + File.separator +filename;

    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();

    }

    try {

        byte[] l_bytes = p_file.getBytes();
        Path l_path = Paths
                .get(directoryName + File.separator +  p_file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(l_path, l_bytes);

        savefile.setStatus(com.main.general.ResultConstent.STATUS_OK);


    } catch (IOException e) {

        savefile.addErrormessage("Exception occured while saving file in Doc Server");

    }

    return savefile;
}
```

Comment: If I understand it `docServerService.transferFileToDocServer` is what forwards the upload (to the app server) file.  So what does `docServerService.transferFileToDocServer` actually look like?